# Get full width of an element when it has absolutely positioned child elements inside it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/meYnS/3/

Lets say I have an element `.outer` with 100px width and `position:relative;`. It has an inner element which has `position:absolute;` and `left:95px;`. I.e. the child element exceeds the width of the parent element.

Now, in JQUery, if I try to get the width of the parent using `$('.outer').outerWidth();` it return 100.

But how can I get the full width of the outer element (which is obviously greater than 100, because of the absolutely positioned child element)?

Is there a built-in way or do I have to do a manual calculation (i.e. adding each child width to parent width to figure out the full width)?

Comment: The last option, I'm afraid. The only easier way would be to write a recursive function to check all the children (until the deepest) and return the smallest number for top and left, greatest number for right and bottom.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the properties `scrollWidth`, `scrollHeight`.

If you are using jQuery,

```
$('.outer').get(0).scrollWidth
```

Comment: That is awesome! Seems to work on my example here: http://jsfiddle.net/gsZL9/1/ However, it should be noted that although it does indeed calculate what Veera's asking for, the `.outer` element itself still renders at 100px wide.

Comment: As you have set it's positioning to `relative` it will not resize automatically. You have write code to do it.

Answer (score 3):

You've set the width at 100px and the child element is positioned absolute, so it will not affect the width of the its parent. The parent's width is still truly 100px.

Comment: My feeling, also. If the child elements are absolutely positioned, they're not growing the parent, period. If you temporarily modify your CSS to put borders around these, you will likely see that the child is going outside the confines of the parent, not growing it.

Comment: Fiddle showing that the parent doesn't grow when the child is absolutely positioned: http://jsfiddle.net/gsZL9/

Answer (score 0):

jQuery does not provide an access to the javascript property `scrollWidth`, so you have to access a DOM element using jQuery.

jQuery[.get()](http://api.jquery.com/get/) is a method for you to achieve a DOM element.

therefore, the solution using jQuery is `$('.outer').get(0).scrollWidth`

If you use origin javascript, the solution would be `document.getElementsByClassName('outer')[0].scrollWidth`